# ASP net core: Configure response serialization culture per controller and/or action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I have an application with multiple controllers that are used in different scenarios. This means different controllers need a different strategy to determine the correct culture to use for the response. Some examples for the different ways to determine the culture (in pseudo C# code)

- user.culture ?? accept-language
- accept-language ?? setting.GetCustomValue(controllerXCulture)
- accept-language

The `RequestCultureProvider` only receives a `HttpContext`, so I'm missing the `ControllerActionContext`, to be able to determine the selection strategy. Or does someone know how to get it?

Adding middleware to set the thread culture also doesn't work. It will set the desired culture during execution of the action, but when the response is serialized, the original culture determined by the standard RequestCultureProviders will be restored, resulting in a response in the incorrect culture.

Does anyone know of a way to set the response culture or how to configure a custom `RequestCultureProvider`  per controller?

[edit]
I tried to find workarounds, thinking, maybe I can set the desired culture at some point after having it stored in the `HttpContext.Items`, but I can't find a good point to set it. I went as far as creating a custom output formatter, derived from `NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter`, but that wasn't called, even when I cleared the other formatters first in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. And no other place I set the culture resulted in the culture being set correctly during serialization.
[/edit]

Comment: You can refer to this : https://medium.com/swlh/step-by-step-tutorial-to-build-multi-cultural-asp-net-core-web-app-3fac9a960c43

Comment: @YongqingYu that article does not help. It does not explain different culture selection strategies per action or controller, it defines a single strategy for the whole application. I had already seen that article.

Answer (score 0):

Using a ton of different google search variations, I ended up on this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#using-middleware-in-the-filter-pipeline

It is not the most ideal solution, because I you need to create multiple classes for the different behaviors, but at least it allows me to create custom localization options per controller/action.

This seems the best solution for now, although I hope there might be an even more elegant one. At least this doesn't feel hacky.